# Mesh completely disappears in mobile device with three.js Position issue or camera issue?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, three.js, 3d, gltf

In my scene I added a GLTF 3D model. I used the use effect method to make it responsive but it seems to completely disappears on mobile (Go down).

I've tried different position of the object and different camera position but it always disappears on mobile .
[Desktop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mBD3D.png)

[Mobile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vPY2x.png)

```
import React, { Suspense, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Canvas } from "@react-three/fiber";
import { OrbitControls, Preload, useGLTF } from "@react-three/drei";

import CanvasLoader from "../Loader";

const Computers = ({ isMobile }) => {
  const computer = useGLTF("./desktop_pc/scene.gltf");

  return (
    <mesh>
      <hemisphereLight intensity={0.5} groundColor='black' />
      <spotLight
        position={[-20, 50, 10]}
        angle={0.12}
        penumbra={1}
        intensity={1}
        castShadow
        shadow-mapSize={1024}
      />
      <pointLight intensity={1} />
      <primitive
        object={computer.scene}
        scale={isMobile ? 1 : 1.5}
        position={isMobile ? [-50, -10, -2.2] : [0, -3.25, -1.5]}
        rotation={[-0.01, -0.2, -0.1]}
      />
    </mesh>
  );
};

const ComputersCanvas = () => {
  const [isMobile, setIsMobile] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    // Add a listener for changes to the screen size
    const mediaQuery = window.matchMedia("(max-width: 500px)");

    // Set the initial value of the `isMobile` state variable
    setIsMobile(mediaQuery.matches);

    // Define a callback function to handle changes to the media query
    const handleMediaQueryChange = (event) => {
      setIsMobile(event.matches);
    };

    // Add the callback function as a listener for changes to the media query
    mediaQuery.addEventListener("change", handleMediaQueryChange);

    // Remove the listener when the component is unmounted
    return () => {
      mediaQuery.removeEventListener("change", handleMediaQueryChange);
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <Canvas
      frameloop='demand'
      shadows
      dpr={[1, 2]}
      camera={{ position: [20, 3, 5], fov: 25 }}
      gl={{ preserveDrawingBuffer: true }}
    >
      <Suspense fallback={<CanvasLoader />}>
        <OrbitControls
          enableZoom={true}
          //maxPolarAngle={Math.PI / 2}
          //minPolarAngle={Math.PI / 2}
        />
        <Computers isMobile={isMobile} />
      </Suspense>

      <Preload all />
    </Canvas>
  );
};

export default ComputersCanvas;
```

I've tried different position of the object and different camera position.